# revoking drop or truncate on a specific object on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am building a database for students. I want the students to be able to perform any action on the database, create tables etc. I do not want them to delete the master table.
So far, I granted them almost all the permissions using this grant

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD,
 PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES,
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE,
 REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, 
 CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER 
 ON *.* 
 TO 'mta_student'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

However, how can I keep them from interfering with master_table I have?
a data table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't revoke a specific privilege that hasn't been granted specifically. In this case, you haven't granted access per table, so you can't revoke access per table.

The only way to accomplish what you describe is to locate your `master_table` in a separate schema:

```
create schema main;
rename table master_table to main.master_table;
```

Then grant your students privileges on other schemas, but not the `main` schema.

```
grant ... on student_schema.* to 'mta_student'@'%';
```